# Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)\le \mu (A)+\epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ a measure space. Let $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ where each $A_n\in S$. Suppose $\mu (A)<\infty$ and  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)\le \mu (A)+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Show that:

a) $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E\cap A_n)\le \mu (E\cap A)+\epsilon$ for every $E\in S$.

b) Let $C$ the set of all $x\in A$ such that $x\in A_n$ for at least two $n$. Then $C\in S$ and $\mu (C)\le \epsilon$.

I tried this:

a) It is easy to see that there exists $(B_n)$ a sequence of disjoint measurable sets such that $B_n\subseteq A_n$ and $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=A$.

Thus $\mu(E\cap A)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E\cap B_n)$, but I don't know if this will work...

b) I think that:

$C=\displaystyle\bigcup\left\{{\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in J}A_n:|J|\ge 2, J\subseteq\mathbb{N}}\right\}$

Hence measurable. But how can we show that $\mu (C)\le \epsilon$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First I should note that we are probably using $\mu(A)<\infty$ for countability from below somewhere in here, but I haven't checked where.

1. This approach will work. $\bigsqcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}B_{n}=A$ and measures satisfy countable disjoint additivity, so we have
   $$
   \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_{n})\leq\mu(A)+\epsilon=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(B_{n})+\epsilon
   $$
   Subtracting, we find
   $$
   \epsilon\geq\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_{n})-\mu(B_{n})=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_{n}\setminus B_{n})
   $$
   again using disjoint additivity (since $B_{n}\sqcup(A_{n}\setminus B_{n})=A_{n}$). Now we can similarly split $E$ into the part intersecting with $B_{n}$ and the part intersecting with $A_{n}\setminus B_{n}$:
   $$
   \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(E\cap A_{n})=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(E\cap B_{n})+\mu(E\cap(A_{n}\setminus B_{n}))\leq\mu(E\cap A)+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_{n}\cap B_{n})
   $$
   which is in turn bounded above by $\mu(E\cap A)+\epsilon$, using disjoint additivity to get $\mu(E\cap A)$ and monotonicity ($E\cap(A_{n}\setminus B_{n})\subseteq A_{n}\setminus B_{n}$) along with our previous inequality to get $\epsilon$.
2. I believe your proof that $C\in S$ is technically incorrect since it gives $C$ as an uncountable union (there are uncountably many such $J$s) of measurable sets, and this is not guaranteed to be measurable. However, you may rewrite your expression for $C$ as
   $$
   C=\bigcup_{\substack{i,j\in\mathbb{N}\\i\neq j}}A_{i}\cap A_{j}
   $$
   (it suffices to take intersections of just two sets), which is a countable union of measurable sets, and so $C\in S$.
   To show that $\mu(C)\leq\epsilon$, use what we just proved. We have
   $$
   \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(C\cap A_{n})\leq\mu(C\cap A)+\epsilon=\mu(C)+\epsilon
   $$
   Intuitively, the sum of the lefthand side is at least double-counting every bit of $C$, since every element of $C$ appears in at least two $A_{n}$s.
   Let's show that this double-counts every bit of $C$. We build $C$ by iterating over the $A_{n}$s and keeping the *new* repeats. Construct a sequence $\{C_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by $C_{0}=\emptyset$ and
   $$
   C_{n}=\left(\bigsqcup_{m<n}A_{n}\cap B_{m}\right)\setminus\left(\bigsqcup_{m<n}C_{m}\right)
   $$
   The left disjoint union grabs all the repeats (everything in $A_{n}$ and was also $A_{m}$ for some $m<n$); the right disjoint union discards the 'repeated repeats.'
   Using countable disjount additivity we have
   $$
   \mu(C)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_{n}
   $$
   But now we have both $C_{n}\subseteq C\cap A_{n}$ and $C_{n}\subseteq\bigcup_{m<n}C\cap A_{m}$ and so, summing,
   $$
   \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(C\cap A_{n})\geq 2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(C\cap C_{n})=2\mu(C)
   $$
   This last bit feels shaky, but you get the idea and it looks like someone else has already answered more concisely. Please let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use integral, but just for non-negative step functions (you can use $\int\sum a_n\,\chi_{C_n}\,d\mu=\sum a_n\,\mu(C_n)$, $C_n$'s disjoint, as a definition, and check that $\int\sum a_n\,\chi_{C_n}\,d\mu=\sum a_n\,\mu(C_n)$ ($a_n\geq0$) even if $C_n$'s are not disjoint, by refining $C_n$'s).

The inequality says that $\int\sum\chi_{A_n}\,d\mu\leq\mu(A)+\epsilon$, i.e. $\int(-1+\sum\chi_{A_n})\,d\mu\leq\epsilon$, but then $\int(-1+\sum\chi_{A_n})\chi_E\,d\mu\leq\epsilon$ as $0\leq(-1+\sum\chi_{A_n})\chi_E\leq-1+\sum\chi_{A_n}$. This solves a).

For b), let $f(x)=1$ for $x$'s which are in a single $A_n$, and $f(x)=2$ for those which are in at least two. As $f\leq \sum\chi_{A_n}$, you get $\int(f-1)d\mu\leq\int(-1+\sum\chi_{A_n})\,d\mu\leq\epsilon$, as you wanted.